# Selenium: Access Parts of Scrollbar Using CSS Selector

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

This is the xpath for accessing the elements of a scrollbar.

```
/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/div/table[4]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]
```

I copied this XPATH using Firepath but it's very long and susceptible to change.I wanted to access the elements using css selector but I'm not quite sure how to do it. Below is the HTML file of the scrollbar.

Question: How can I access the Home, Previous, Next, End starting from the 'class="z-biglistbox-one z-biglistbox" '? The xpath earlier access the Next button. If you have any ideas how to do it, can you please share it. Thank you.

```
<div id="pRCQhu3" class="z-biglistbox-one z-biglistbox" style="width:1100px;height:800px;">
   <div class="z-biglistbox-outer">
       <div id="pRCQhu3-head" class="z-biglistbox-head-outer">
       <div id="pRCQhu3-body" class="z-biglistbox-body-outer" style="height: 653px;">
       <a id="pRCQhu3-a" class="z-focus-a" style="top:0px;left:0px" onclick="return false;" href="javascript:;"></a>
       <div id="pRCQhu3-vbar" class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-vertical">
       <div id="pRCQhu3-hbar" class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-horizontal">
            <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-drag" style="left: 0px;">
               <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-home" title="Home"></div>
               <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-up" title="Previous"></div>
               <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-down" title="Next"></div>
               <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-end" title="End"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note: There are other elements that have the same class name. When I tried to use the class name those elements are accessed instead of these ones. I was wondering if I can use something like this because these are the 2nd use of that class:

```
WebElement down = driver.findElement(By.className("z-biglistbox-wscroll-down[2]"));
```

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not access these elements using 'By.className'?

```
WebElement homeButton = driverGC.FindElement(
       By.ClassName("z-biglistbox-wscroll-home"));
```

Comment: I can't use class name because there are other elements which have the same class name. Those elements appear before these ones so when I use the class name those elements are the ones accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate them using the class name

```
WebElement homeButton = driver.findElement(By.className("z-biglistbox-wscroll-home"));
WebElement homeButton = driver.findElement(By.className("z-biglistbox-wscroll-up"));
//...
```

Or with partial class name using `cssSelector`

```
WebElement homeButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class*='home']"));
WebElement homeButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class*='up']"));
//...
```

Comment: Sadly, can't use class name because there are other elements which have the same class name. Those elements appear before these ones so when I use the class name those elements are the ones accessed.

Comment: @Andrea Is the id `"pRCQhu3-hbar"` in the ancestor element unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can use class name for this

For Home button

```
WebElement homeButton = driver.findElement(By.className("z-biglistbox-wscroll-home"));
homeButton.click();
```

For Up button

```
WebElement upButton = driver.findElement(By.className("z-biglistbox-wscroll-up"));
upButton.click();
```

For Down button

```
WebElement downButton = driver.findElement(By.className("z-biglistbox-wscroll-down"));
downButton.click();
```

For End button

```
WebElement endButton = driver.findElement(By.className("z-biglistbox-wscroll-end"));
endButton.click();
```

Comment: I can't use class name because there are other elements which have the same class name. Those elements appear before these ones so when I use the class name those elements are the ones accessed.